# Iphone sdk setting object attributes with array (sqlite3)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios4, object, sqlite

Not sure if this is possible in Iphone sdk since i have not been able to get it working.
I have an object called Client, and it has the following properties.

```
  firstName, lastName, mobile, email.
```

i then set it up by doing the following

```
  Client *clientObj = [[Client alloc] init:];
```

i then set up an array with the following values, which has the exact attribute names for Client.

```
  NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"firstName", @"lastName", @"email", @"mobile", nil]
```

now, is it possible to do something like this

```
  clientObj.[myArray objectAtIndex:0] = @"Robert";
```

to get the same effect as doing

```
  clientObj.firstName = @"Robert";
```

Has anyone been able to do something similar? The reason i am doing it this way is that i have an IF statement that checks if an sql statement returns a null value for a field, so therefore it wont assign it to the clientObj and the only way i thought i could iterate through the attributes of Client is to set up and array which has those attributes.

This was a section of my code i was working on.

```
  Client *clientObj = [[Client alloc] init];

  int i;

  NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"firstName", @"lastName", @"email", @"mobile", nil];

  for(i=0;i < [myArray count];i++){

  char *tempChar = sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, i);                            

  if (tempChar == nil) {
     //is null dont assign
  } else { 
     clientObj.[myArray objectAtIndex:i] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, i)];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the dot syntax use KVC `[clientObj setValue:@"Robert" forKey:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];`